# printf: supplying variables without formatting

Tags: printf

Is it legal to use variables in printf without supplying the formatting (such as %d, %f).
for example:

```
 printf("value is ok\r\n",myvalue);
```

The command compiles without errors nor warning, though I am not absolutely sure if it is legal or dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) says

> There should be at least as many of these arguments as the number of values specified in the format specifiers. Additional arguments are ignored by the function.

Base on this information, your statement is perfectly legal, however I don't thinks that this is a good idea, since you code could quickly become confusing, which might lead to bugs.

---

**Edit:** The original source does not explicitly mention the case of *zero* arguments. To add another source, the [linux man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) states

> The format string is composed of zero or more directives.

This source does not discuss what happens with additional arguments. However, combining these two sources gives a definitive answer.